# Trying to identify old 2x4 plate

Tags: part-identification

Another odd-ball in my endless sorting and cleaning: a basic 2x4 black plate, but with two raised hollow tubes, larger than a stud. No part number. Here's a picture of it:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This 2x4 plate belongs to the

- **housing of an old 4.5V train motor**.

[image]

[image]

There are some scratches on the edge of your plate, most likely from an attempt to pry it off with a screwdriver.

Comment: I think you are correct @Uli, the marks you noticed appear to be from the glue that held it to the motor housing. I have a better picture of the surface but I am not sure how to add it without messing something up.